# How to create hasOne relation in laravel based on column value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have table "elements" which has two columns "object" and "object_id".
Object column can be "picture" or "video". I want to make a relation in elements model

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Content\Picture', 'id', 'object_id');
```

This works fine if object == "picture" but I want do make a condition,
if object is video - relation to be to Video model.

Comment: this is where you use morph relation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#morph-to-relationships

Comment: just define relationship hasOne for your both model and call as per object